# Select one dimension of Multidimensional array with list - numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D array of shape `(800,5,4)` like:

```
arr = array([[35.  , 33.  , 33.  ,  0.15],
       [47.  , 47.  , 44.  ,  0.19],
       [49.  , 56.  , 60.  ,  0.31],
       ...,
       [30.  , 27.  , 25.  ,  0.07],
       [54.  , 49.  , 42.  ,  0.14],
       [33.  , 30.  , 28.  ,  0.22]])
```

I have a 1D array of indeces for the second dimension (so they range from 0 to 4) like this:

```
indeces = [0,3,2,0,1,1,1,0,...,0,1,2,2,4,3]
```

I want to select the `idx` item from the second dimension, and get back an array of shape `(800,4)`

I have tried the following but could not make it work:

```
indexed = arr[:,indeces,:]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your result will be of size (800,len(indeces), 4) as you are selecting from that middle index many times. If you want it to be (800,4) than you can only select one index like arr[:,indeces[0],:].

Comment: Post the error message you are getting

Answer (score 1):

```
In [178]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

If I have a list of 7 items:

```
In [179]: idx = [0,1,1,2,2,0,1]                                                                  
In [180]: arr[:,idx,:]                                                                           
Out[180]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23],
        [20, 21, 22, 23],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19]]])
In [181]: _.shape                                                                                
Out[181]: (2, 7, 4)
```

To produce a (2,4) result, we have to pick one element on the 2nd dim for each of pair from the other dimensions.

A general case would be to make `idx` a (2,4) array, and index with dimensions that also broadcast to (2,4):

```
In [182]: idx = np.array([0,1,1,2,2,0,1,0]).reshape(2,4)                                         
In [183]: arr[np.arange(2)[:,None],idx,np.arange(4)]                                             
Out[183]: 
array([[ 0,  5,  6, 11],
       [20, 13, 18, 15]])
In [184]: _.shape                                                                                
Out[184]: (2, 4)
```

Or we could pick with a scalar:

```
In [185]: arr[:,2,:]                                                                             
Out[185]: 
array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

`@a_guest` showed how to do this with an `idx` that matches the 1st dimension (and slices the last).

One way or other your `idx` has to map or broadcast with the other dimensions.

Comment: Would you consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327803/using-a-mask-for-a-3d-numpy-array-return-2d-array a duplicate of this question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also select the remaining dimensions "row-by-row". That is you need to supply an index array of the following form: `range(arr.shape[0])`. For example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> i = [0, 1, 2]
>>> a[range(a.shape[0]), i, :]
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [24, 25, 26]])
>>> a[range(a.shape[0]), i, range(a.shape[2])]
array([ 0, 13, 26])
```