# Using a mask for a 3D numpy array -> return 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, mask

What I have:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
dlen = 250000
data = np.random.rand(dlen, 3, 3)
mask = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2], dlen)
```

What I want to get:

```
[[0.37454012 0.95071431 0.73199394], 
 [0.83244264 0.21233911 0.18182497], 
 [0.13949386 0.29214465 0.36636184], 
 [0.94888554 0.96563203 0.80839735], 
 [0.44015249 0.12203823 0.49517691],
 ....
(250000, 3)
```

What I try to use for this:

```
data[:,mask,:]

{MemoryError}Unable to allocate 1.36 TiB for an array with shape (250000, 250000, 3) and data type float64
```

What gives the correct result but looks strange:

```
data[np.arange(data.shape[0]), mask, :]
```

So what's the correct way to use this mask?

Upd.:
The mask should select the column with the specified index. Example for an array with shape [2,3,3]:

```
array = [[[5 6 7], [7 8 9], [2 3 4]],
         [[2 1 0], [7 6 5], [7 6 5]]]
mask = [1 0]
result = [[7 8 9], 
          [2 1 0]]
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what your mask is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Tried to explain in the question.

Comment: your given example array has only 2 axis not 3

Comment: `..gives the correct result but looks strange` - That works because your are *using* an [Index array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: These are the three axis in the example now.

Comment: `arr[ [0,1,2], [0,1,2] ]` selects the diagonal of a (3,3) array.  Your "strange" indexing does the same sort of thing.  Your 2 1d arrays work together to select elements along the first 2 dimensions of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data[np.arange(data.shape[0]), mask, :]
```

That works because it is a [multi-dimensional index array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)

When I here the term *mask* I think of boolean indexing. Your integer mask can be converted to a boolean mask to  use it the way you want.

```
>>> data.shape                 
(250000, 3, 3)
>>> mask.shape
(250000,)
>>> q = mask[:,None] == [0,1,2]
>>> q.shape
(250000, 3)
>>> q[:5]        
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]])
>>> r = data[q]
>>> r.shape
(250000, 3)
>>> r[:10]
array([[0.37454012, 0.95071431, 0.73199394],
       [0.83244264, 0.21233911, 0.18182497],
       [0.13949386, 0.29214465, 0.36636184],
       [0.94888554, 0.96563203, 0.80839735],
       [0.44015249, 0.12203823, 0.49517691],
       [0.66252228, 0.31171108, 0.52006802],
       [0.59789998, 0.92187424, 0.0884925 ],
       [0.14092422, 0.80219698, 0.07455064],
       [0.00552212, 0.81546143, 0.70685734],
       [0.31098232, 0.32518332, 0.72960618]])
>>>
```

You could use the second dimension *length* to make is a little more generic:

```
q = mask[:,None] == np.arange(data.shape[1])
>>> q[:5]                                        
array([[ True, False, False], 
       [False,  True, False], 
       [False,  True, False], 
       [False, False,  True], 
       [False,  True, False]])
```

---

If you control *construction* of the mask, you might want to construct it as a boolean array.

---

If this is new code, you might want to upgrade to a compatible version of Numpy and use the *new* [random generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

For the construction of the mask I use


`mask = np.argmin(some_array, axis=1)`


Instead  I can do something like this:


`boolean_mask = np.min(some_array, axis=1)[:, None] == some_array`


Just a note for me.